# I/P-a string S.O/P: For each digit start from 0-9,print count of their occurrence in S.Print10 lines,each line contain 2 space separated integers

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
```

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        int count=0,count2=0,count3=0,count4=0,count5=0,count6=0,count7=0,count8=0,count9=0,count1=0,i;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int []a=new int[5];       

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==0)
        {count++;}

        if(a[i]==1)
        {count1++;}

        if(a[i]==2)
        {count2++;}

        if(a[i]==3)
        {count3++;}

        if(a[i]==4)
        {count4++;}

        if(a[i]==5)
        {count5++;}

        if(a[i]==6)
        {count6++;}

        if(a[i]==7)
        {count7++;}

        if(a[i]==8)
        {count8++;}

        if(a[i]==9)
        {count9++;} 

    }
        System.out.println("0"+count);
        System.out.println("1"+count1);
        System.out.println("2"+count2);
        System.out.println("3"+count3);
        System.out.println("4"+count4);
        System.out.println("5"+count5);
        System.out.println("6"+count6);
        System.out.println("7"+count7);
        System.out.println("8"+count8);
        System.out.println("9"+count9);

}
```

}

Comment: Is it too much to ask you to 1) explain your code, 2) tell what's wrong with it, and to 3) add detailed text in your post that resembles an actual specific and answerable question?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here:

```
  int []a=new int[5];
```

you array is not enough

replace it like this:

```
  int []a=new int[10];
```

and show something because user do not know what its happening

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("add number");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
```

if you change your code as me

like this:

```
package teteo;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prueba {


      public static void main(String[] args){

           int count = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, count4 = 0, count5 = 0, count6 = 0, count7 = 0, count8 = 0, count9 = 0, count1 = 0, i;
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

      int []a=new int[10];    

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("add number");
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==0)
            {count++;}

            if(a[i]==1)
            {count1++;}

            if(a[i]==2)
            {count2++;}

            if(a[i]==3)
            {count3++;}

            if(a[i]==4)
            {count4++;}

            if(a[i]==5)
            {count5++;}

            if(a[i]==6)
            {count6++;}

            if(a[i]==7)
            {count7++;}

            if(a[i]==8)
            {count8++;}

            if(a[i]==9)
            {count9++;} 

        }
            System.out.println("0"+count);
            System.out.println("1"+count1);
            System.out.println("2"+count2);
            System.out.println("3"+count3);
            System.out.println("4"+count4);
            System.out.println("5"+count5);
            System.out.println("6"+count6);
            System.out.println("7"+count7);
            System.out.println("8"+count8);
            System.out.println("9"+count9);

    }

}
```

you will get something like this

```
add number
1
add number
2
add number
3
add number
4
add number
5
add number
6
add number
7
add number
8
add number
9
add number
0
01
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
```

Comment: I got your point. But I want the output of arr[5]. Eg. Input - 22675 then output must be 00 10 22 30 40 51 61 71 80 90

Comment: then what you need isthat when user fill the numbers you will have to iterate your array record by record

Comment: Can you explain it with the code like you previously explained?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you start using loops for this task.

See the following piece of code:

```
public class CountDigits {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = readInput();
        int[] counts = countDigits(s);
        printResult(counts);
    }

    private static String readInput() {
        System.out.println("Please enter a line of text (possibly containing digits):");
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            return scanner.next();
        }
    }

    private static int[] countDigits(String s) {
        int[] counts = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                int d = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(c));
                counts[d]++;
            }
        }
        return counts;
    }

    private static void printResult(int[] counts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            System.out.format("%d %d\n", i, counts[i]);
        }
    }
}
```